# Verification of proof of propositional logic

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I made a proof for the following theorem. But I'm not completely certain that it's fully correct.

> Suppose $\phi$ is a propositional formula and that the two evaluations $v$ and $w$ are equal for all atoms that appear in $\phi$. Then is $\overline v(\phi)$ = $\overline w(\phi)$.

Proof: We deliver a proof by induction on the length of $\phi$.

Induction basis: Suppose $l(\phi) = 1$. Then $\phi$ is an atom. Thus $\overline v(\phi) = \overline w(\phi)$.

Induction step: Suppose $l(\phi) > 1$. Then we must distinguish various cases:

1) Suppose $\phi = \phi_1 \wedge \phi_2$. Then $l(\phi_1) < l(\phi)$ and $l(\phi_2) < l(\phi)$. By induction we find that $\overline v(\phi_1) = \overline w(\phi_1)$ and $\overline v(\phi_2) = \overline w(\phi_2)$. Successively we find that $\overline v(\phi) = \overline v(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv \overline v(\phi_1) \wedge \overline v(\phi_2) \equiv \overline w(\phi_1) \wedge \overline w(\phi_2) \equiv \overline w(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv \overline w(\phi)$.

We find the other cases completely analog to 1).

Now I'm not sure whether it's true that $\overline v(\phi) = \overline w(\phi)$ in my induction basis? And if it's legal to write $\overline v(\phi) = \overline v(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2)$?

Comment: It's true, and it's legal — respectively. In the basis, $\bar{v}(\phi) = v(\phi)  = w(\phi)  = \bar{w}(\phi)$, so what's not to be sure about? In the induction step, $\phi = (\phi_1\land\phi_2)$, so what could your apprehension be about $\bar{v}(\phi) = \bar{v}(\phi_1\land\phi_2)$?

Comment: Thank you very much! In the basis I wasn't sure in what matter I had to take account of the fact that there could be other atoms in $v$ or $w$. And in my course it's stated that $\overline v(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv T$ iff $\overline v(\phi_1) \equiv T$ and $\overline v(\phi_2) \equiv T$. I wasn't completely sure that I simply could write $\overline v(\phi_1 \wedge \phi_2) \equiv \overline v(\phi_1) \wedge \overline v(\phi_2)$.

Comment: Well, that's a different worry from the one you mention in the last line of the  question. In fact, it's good to be concerned about the point you just mentioned. The second $\land$ should at least be another symbol or *and* (italics deliberate), because there, you're speaking in the metalanguage whereas $\land$ is a symbol of the language. Thus, "$\bar{v}(\phi_1\land \phi_2) = \bar{v}(\phi_1)\text{ $and$ } \bar{v}(\phi_2)$", and similarly *not* for $\neg$, *or* for $\lor$,  etc. These actually will denote operators on truth values, whereas $\neg, \land, ...$ are connectives, mere symbols.

Comment: PS If italics are too subtle, then boldface or sans serif — some style that's not ordinary text.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! It's clear to me how it works now :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @BrianO Can you please transform your comments into an answer?

Comment: There, I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, and it's legal — respectively.

There's no need to be uneasy about the base case:
$$\overline{v}(\phi) = v(\phi) = w(\phi) = \overline{w}(\phi).$$

However, in the chain of identities for the induction step, there is one concern, though actually it's not the one you ask about. If $\phi = \phi_1\land\phi_2$, then of course $\overline{v}(\phi) = \overline{v}(\phi_1\land\phi_2)$ — no worry there. Here's the worry: it's at best confusing and at worst just incorrect to write "$\overline{v}(\phi_1\land\phi_2) = \overline{v}(\phi_1)\land\overline{v}(\phi_2)$".

The $\land$ on the righthand side should be another symbol or, for example, $\mathsf{and}$, because there, you're speaking in the metalanguage whereas $\land$ is a symbol of the language. On the righthand side, you're combining values of $\overline{v}$, which are truth values, so you must combine them with an operator on truth values. On the lefthand side, $\land$, like $\lor$ and $\neg$, is a connective, a mere symbol. It's important to distinguish between these domains and levels of discourse. Thus, the identity should be 
$$
\overline{v}(\phi_1\land\phi_2) = \overline{v}(\phi_1) \operatorname{\mathsf{and}} \overline{v}(\phi_2)
$$
or something like it. You might use $\&$, for example, instead of $\operatorname{\mathsf{and}}$; but it's best not to overload $\land$.